# Preventing execution of a function if an alert has been triggered at the same time from a different function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> *Question*

Action **A** triggers function **B** and function **C** concurrently(?!).
If **B** throws alert can I
 prevent **C** from executing, perhaps, by using some kind of general listener function?

The solution I seek, does not involve adding specific listener to function **C**, it must remain generalised.

---

> My Example

I have the following code below that gets triggered when a button within a modal is pressed. This deletes the contents until a GET method is processed and user is returned to the redirected page.

```
$( ".loadingEnabled" ).click(function( event ) {
    $(".loadingSpinner").css("display","block");
    $(".myModalContent").hide();
    $(".modal-header").html("<b>Processing your request</b>");
    $(".modal-footer").hide();
});
```

Within the modal I have just few simple validation scripts,e.g.,:

```
    } else if ($("#name").val().length < 2){
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("You cannot proceed without entering your name")
  }
```

So with the current set up, the user will trigger the `loadingEnabled` click function, however, if the data is not valid the `loadingEnabled` will trigger `hide()` and `css()` indefinitely as the `submit` dissapears and `preventDefault()` is triggered.

Question is, can I introduce something in `loadingEnabled` function that would prevent it from executing, if an `alert` is triggered?

I can think of workarounds. I am just wondering if there is anything for such a case.

Comment: How about using a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

a couple of suggestions.

1. You could return a boolean from your validation and make the loadingEnabled code conditional on that:

   ```
   $( ".loadingEnabled" ).click(function( event ) {
   if(validation()){
       $(".loadingSpinner").css("display","block");
       $(".myModalContent").hide();
       $(".modal-header").html("<b>Processing your request</b>");
       $(".modal-footer").hide();
           }
      });
   ```

then (in validation function) :

```
return true; // assuming that validation has passed
} else if ($("#name").val().length < 2){
event.preventDefault();
alert("You cannot proceed without entering your name")
return false;
}
```

or 2. You could invert your flow, calling the validation function on button click, name the other function and only call that if validation passes

Comment: Loading enabled is used in several places, validating name just in one. Wouldn't your solution be too specific, i.e., loading enabled wouldn't work elsewhere?

Comment: I guess in that case you could add a paramater to the validate function call telling it where it was getting called from

Comment: But it sounds like my 2nd option might be simpler to implement

Comment: The thing is I wanted to avoid naming functions as this would make functions co-dependent.

Comment: I guess it's hard to know what that means while only looking at snippets

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a the solution I had in mind, however, the solution I implemented involved:

1. instantiating a new global variable `validated` to `true`
2. positioning `loadingEnabled` function after `validation` function in order for the system to execute `validation` first.
3. Added a line in each failed validation to set `validated` to `false` if input was not valid and if all validation passed set `validated` to `true`
4. Set a conditional `if statement`  to only execute `loadingEnabled` if `validation` is `true`.

The above solution ensured that `loadingEnabled` can be re-used.